# Faced problems with Adapter in android, What wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Today,I suddenly faced the problem that I never seen before. Help me :)

```
  public class ShowAnimalsListActivity extends Activity
  {
        ArrayList<String> animalsNameList;
        public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.animal_list);

               // Get the reference of ListViewAnimals
                ListView animalList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewAnimals);


                 animalsNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                 getAnimalNames();

                 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
                 new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item1, animalsNameList);
                 // Set The Adapter
                 animalList.setAdapter(
                 animalList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                             // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
                            {

                                    String selectedAnimal=animalsNameList.get(position);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animal Selected : "+selectedAnimal,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem? You don't mention what's wrong.

Comment: Post the error that you got

Comment: Before you do anything else, fix this... Your `animalList.setAdapter(` is not complete, change it to `animalList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the adapter first and then you write onClickListener.

```
animalList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

also change

```
String selectedAnimal=animalsNameList.get(position);
```

to

```
String selectedAnimal=String.ValueOf(animalsNameList.get(position));
```